# Split Rows into several Rows based on a Column Threshold

Tags: r, split, dplyr

I have a dataset like the following:

```
dat2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID  LT  LF  Dist  TM  NM
a001    0   3   3 p001    pn07
                   a003 4.1 4.9 0.8 p002    pn08
                   a004 2.1 6.6 4.5 p003    pn09
                   a008 8.7 12    3.3 p004    pn10
                   a009 2   4.3 2.3 p005    pn11
                   a010 1   4   3 p006    pn12
                   a023 1   3   2 p007    pn13
                   a024 1   3   2 p008    pn14
                   ")

dat2
    ID  LT   LF Dist   TM   NM
1 a001 0.0  3.0  3.0 p001 pn07
2 a003 4.1  4.9  0.8 p002 pn08
3 a004 2.1  6.6  4.5 p003 pn09
4 a008 8.7 12.0  3.3 p004 pn10
5 a009 2.0  4.3  2.3 p005 pn11
6 a010 1.0  4.0  3.0 p006 pn12
7 a023 1.0  3.0  2.0 p007 pn13
8 a024 1.0  3.0  2.0 p008 pn14
```

I want to split the rows based on the `Dist` threshold. if `Dist >=2.0` it will divide the rows into several rows. `LT` and `LF` are also needed to be changed accordingly. For example, consider `a002`. It has `Dist` of 4.5. It starts with `LT=2.1` and ends with `LF=6.6`. For split rows, the `LT` and `LF` would be like the following:

```
a002: LT=2.1 LF=4.1 (calculation= 2.1+`Dist=2`) Dist=2
a002: LT=4.1 LF=6.1 (calculation= 4.1+`Dist=2`) Dist=2
a002: LT=6.1 LF=6.6 (endpoint,LF is `6.6` and `Dist < 2`) Dist=0.5
```

The final output would be:

```
   ID   LT   LF Dist   TM   NM
1  a001  0.0  2.0  2.0 p001 pn07
2  a001  2.0  3.0  1.0 p001 pn07
3  a003  4.1  4.9  0.8 p002 pn08
4  a004  2.1  4.1  2.0 p003 pn09
5  a004  4.1  6.1  2.0 p003 pn09
6  a004  6.1  6.6  0.5 p003 pn09
7  a008  8.7 10.7  2.0 p004 pn10
8  a008 10.7 12.0  1.3 p004 pn10
9  a009  2.0  4.0  2.0 p005 pn11
10 a009  4.0  4.3  0.3 p005 pn11
11 a010  1.0  3.0  2.0 p006 pn12
12 a010  3.0  4.0  1.0 p006 pn12
13 a023  1.0  3.0  2.0 p007 pn13
14 a024  1.0  3.0  2.0 p008 pn14
```

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335423/r-split-data-frame-row-into-two-rows) is here. But not exactly same.

Comment: What is the criteria after you split a row for how you distribute the values between the different rows. I see that no difference should be over 2, but i cant find the pattern on how you asigning values to LT and LF

Comment: `Dist` is the difference between `LT` and `LF`. It is some kind of identifier for the starting and ending. If the `Dist` between them is above 2, I need to separate the rows into multiple rows in such a way that each `Dist` doesn't acquire segment length over 2. For example, if the `Dist` is 8.3, I need to split that rows into `5 rows (2, 2, 2, 2, 0.3)` and recalculate `DT` and `DF` accordingly.

Comment: I got that part. I'm just a bit confused by the output example. Would it be valid if for example ID=="a001" had two rows like this (LT=0,LF=2, DF=2 & LT=0,LF=1,DF=1)? because I'm not sure why the logic would be to put LT=2 and LF=3 in the second row.

Comment: Thanks. For `a001`, starting point (`LT`) is `0`, and ending point (`LF`) is 3. The `Dist` is 3. As `Dist> 2`, I need to separate it into two rows which have the following `LT` and `LF`: LT=0, LF=2, Dist=2, LT=2( start with previous row's LF), LF=3 (endpoint of original row and `Dist <2`), Dist=1`. Although, partial solutions are also welcome.

Comment: I also have edited the original question slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im sure this is one of the least elegant solutions ever. But it works

```
require(dplyr)
Splitter <- function(rowid){
  TMP <- dat2 %>% filter(ID==rowid) 
  if(TMP$Dist>2){
    TMP1 <- c(rep(x = 2,times=trunc(TMP$Dist/2,0)), TMP$Dist%%2)
    TMP1 <- TMP1[TMP1!=0]
    TMP2 <- data.frame(ID=TMP$ID,LT=TMP$LT,LF=TMP$LF,Dist=TMP1,TM=TMP$TM,NM=TMP$NM)
    for(i in nrow(TMP2):2){
      TMP2[i,2] <- TMP2[i,3] - TMP2[i,4]
      TMP2[i-1,3] <- TMP2[i,2]
    }
  }
  else {TMP2 <- TMP}
  return(TMP2)
  }
FinalDF <- bind_rows(lapply(unique(dat2$ID),Splitter))

> FinalDF
     ID   LT   LF Dist   TM   NM
1  a001  0.0  2.0  2.0 p001 pn07
2  a001  2.0  3.0  1.0 p001 pn07
3  a003  4.1  4.9  0.8 p002 pn08
4  a004  2.1  4.1  2.0 p003 pn09
5  a004  4.1  6.1  2.0 p003 pn09
6  a004  6.1  6.6  0.5 p003 pn09
7  a008  8.7 10.7  2.0 p004 pn10
8  a008 10.7 12.0  1.3 p004 pn10
9  a009  2.0  4.0  2.0 p005 pn11
10 a009  4.0  4.3  0.3 p005 pn11
11 a010  1.0  3.0  2.0 p006 pn12
12 a010  3.0  4.0  1.0 p006 pn12
13 a023  1.0  3.0  2.0 p007 pn13
14 a024  1.0  3.0  2.0 p008 pn14
```